# Microsoft Teams: video meeting window is HUGE on a 4K monitor. Any fixes, including registry settings?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I use a cheap 55" 4K TV as an external monitor over HDMI (laptop screen is too small).

Most programs are all good, and this is like having 4 22" monitors on my desk so I can keep a lot of files open.

However, one program is a problem - when I join MS teams meetings, they are in a separate window as expected. However, the video window *always* opens at about 38 inches (diagonal) on my 55" monitor, so multiple times per day I have to resize and reposition at the start of a meeting.

There are no apparent settings in teams (the zoom setting has no effect on the size of the new video window). Teams does not save the size/position of the last video window from the last meeting.

Are there any other hidden settings, or maybe a registry key that defines either the absolute size of the new video window, or the percentage of the screen it should fill when opening?

Thank you!

Comment: Based on the question description this does not seem like a Teams development question. Could you please help by raising this at :
1) For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/business-video/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online).

Comment: 2) For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).

Comment: Unlike what @Meghana-MSFT says (sorry, but the MS forums are often relatively useless and just get canned responses, in my experience), I'd recommend posting this on superuser. This isn't really a programming question (but still a worthwile question asking elsewhere).